# R assignment operator ("<-")

Tags: r

How does one typeset the R assignment operator ("<-")?  Workarounds such as

```
\begin{description}
    \item[x \textless{}- c(1:3)] Create the vector [1 2 3] and assign it to an object named x.  %Illustrates workaround 1.
    \item[y $\leftangle$- c(10.4, 5.6, 3.1)] Create the vector [10.4 5.6 3.1] and assign it to an object named y.  %Illustrates workaround 2.
    \item[z $\leftarrow$ c(3.1, 6.4, 21.7)] Create the vector [3.1 6.4 21.7] and assign it to an object named z.  %Illustrates workaround 3.
\end{description}
```

are less than satisfactory.

Comment: Is `\texttt{<-}` enough for you?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'd say ``\item[\texttt{x <- c(1:3)}]`` to underline the fact it's code. Also `[1 2 3]` might be `$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$` because it's math.

Comment: You could also use $\leftarrow$ or $\Leftarrow$ if you want something prettier.

Comment: It looks much better if you make the whole assignment into a math formula.  `\item[$y \gets c(1,2,3)$] blah blah....`

Answer (score 13):

The sequence `$\gets$` would do the trick.